# No ping to a network printer connected to a laptop on home wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, network-printer

Given:

- Laptop Alice
- Laptop Bob
- Wireless Router
- Network Printer (LAN, no wifi)
- Alice and Bob are connected to the Router on a wireless network
- The Printer is connected to Bob by an ethernet cable
- Alice can ping Bob's wifi address, but not its wired address. Neither can it ping the Printer
- Bob can ping all

My problem is that I want Alice to be able to ping the Printer, but I have no idea how.

The actual addresses are:

- Alice = 192.168.0.12
- Bob = 192.168.0.6 (wifi) and 192.168.0.2 (wired - static, reserved on the Router)
- Router = 192.168.0.1
- Printer = 192.168.0.5 (static, reserved on the Router)

Right now, Bob can ping the Printer and hence print on it, but not Alice.

I tried to bridge the wifi and Ethernet connections on Bob, but the result was that Bob lost both wifi and ethernet - nothing worked.

I will gladly provide any more information as needed.

How do I configure so that Alice could ping the Printer?

**EDIT1**

- Bob is running Windows 8.1
- Alice is Windows 10 (or Windows 8.1, I have two laptops where each could be Alice)
- Printer is Brother MFC 7360N
- Printer has Gateway configured to 192.168.0.1 currently.
- I have total control over the Printer, the Router, Alice and Bob.

I have tried to bridge the Ethernet and Wireless adapters on Bob, but once bridged I cannot ping google from Bob (my connectivity test). Deleting the bridge restores the ping to google from Bob.

I want to USE the Printer, but I suppose I need to ping it first. I know for sure that Printer answers pings, because Bob can ping it.

I must add that Alice cannot ping the Ethernet address of Bob - 192.168.0.2. I have a feeling that if I get Alice to ping it, then it would also ping the Printer. But with the bridge on Bob not working (I have no idea why) I am kind of lost on how to make it work.

Comment: *"I tried to bridge the wifi and Ethernet connections on Bob"* -- What OS?  Provide details of what you did.

Comment: Do you need Alice to be able to PING the printer or USE the printer? They will require very different steps to accomplish.

Comment: You need to either support bridging, or forwarding on Bob.  Both are probably disabled by default.  Having Bob do forwarding might be easier; I would suggest turning off firewalls when testing (if that is safe to do).  Also, the printer will need to know how to route traffic back to Alice.  That is probably not a problem IF the printer is using Bob as a default gateway.  Otherwise, chances are that IS a problem that will need attention before things work well for you.  I'm posting as a comment instead of an answer because I feel like this info is accurate, but not complete details.  What OS?

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses. I apologize for being silent for two days. Please, see **EDIT1**.

Comment: Changing the default gateway of Printer to Bob (192.168.0.2) does not change anything. Still no ping from Alice, neither to 192.168.0.2 (Bob, wired) nor to 192.168.0.5 (Printer)